# Magento: PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE

Tags: php, magento, parsing, syntax-error

ive tried looking for the answer to this but haven't had any luck. A few days ago our Magento store suddenly stopped working and comes up with a blank white screen no matter what page we try to access, frontend or backend. I managed to find some info in the error log which is repeating this error:

```
[01-Sep-2014 10:27:28 Europe/London] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''*#fubfsdXk5%x5c%x78644f6~6<&w' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) in /home/grippcou/public_html/index.php on line 1
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Show the code please

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Hi John, the file its referencing is the default index page for our Magento install which contains the blowfish password so cant really paste it, not much help i know! I had a look at the link HAL9000 but the error on there assumes the code is wrong when the site has been running fine for months. I havent changed anything on the site in weeks. I had a look at the FTP logs and no one else has accessed it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the index file was corrupted somehow! Going to have to look through logs now.